# Split DataFrame by date and recombine by appending new records and overwriting existing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Edit: I updated the description below to try to make it more clear what I am trying to accomplish.**

I am a fairly new Python user (I usually use R but I am trying to learn Python). I am trying to use pandas to accomplish the following.

I have a DataFrame (`df`) similar to the one below (my real dataset has many more columns):

```
  PROG.ID   TITLE   STATUS   DataDate     
  --------- ------- -------- --------------
  KEY1      Key 1   A        2007-01-01       
  KEY2      Key 2   A        2007-01-01       
  KEY3      Key 3   A        2008-07-01       
  KEY2      Key 2   I        2009-07-01       
  KEY4      Key 4   A        2010-01-01
```

I am trying to output multiple `dataframe`s based on the `DataDate` field like the following:

In `File_2007-01-01.csv`:

```
  PROG.ID   TITLE   STATUS   DataDate     
  --------- ------- -------- --------------
  KEY1      Key 1   A        2007-01-01       
  KEY2      Key 2   A        2007-01-01
```

Both KEY1 and KEY2 added as these are the only records with this date.

In `File_2008-07-01.csv`:

```
  PROG.ID   TITLE   STATUS   DataDate     
  --------- ------- -------- --------------
  KEY1      Key 1   A        2007-01-01       
  KEY2      Key 2   A        2007-01-01       
  KEY3      Key 3   A        2008-07-01
```

KEY3 was added since it was not there.

In `File_2009-07-01.csv`:

```
  PROG.ID   TITLE   STATUS   DataDate     
  --------- ------- -------- --------------
  KEY1      Key 1   A        2007-01-01       
  KEY2      Key 2   I        2009-07-01       
  KEY3      Key 3   A        2008-07-01
```

Notice KEY2 has been replaced with the most recent record. The other records remain unchanged.

And in `File_2009-07-01.csv`:

```
  PROG.ID   TITLE   STATUS   DataDate     
  --------- ------- -------- --------------
  KEY1      Key 1   A        2007-01-01       
  KEY2      Key 2   I        2009-07-01       
  KEY3      Key 3   A        2008-07-01       
  KEY4      Key 4   A        2010-01-01
```

KEY4 was added. Other records remain unchanged.

I have tried using code like the following (but this does not work):

```
df = df.set_index('PROG.ID')
result = pd.DataFrame()
for key, data in df.groupby('DataDate'):
    if result.empty:
        result.data.copy()
    else:
        result.combine_first(data)
        result.update(data)
    result.to_csv('./File_{dt}.csv'.format(dt=key))
```

The first file gets written correctly, but all subsequent files have the same data as the first.

It is my understanding that `combine_first()` will keep all of `result` and add the rows from `data` that are not already in `result`, while `update()` will overwrite the values in `result` by the values in `data` where the keys already exist in `result`. Just for completeness, I tried `update()` before `combine_first()` as well.

Unfortunately, this does not work as expected. I have looked at other questions that have been answered in the past, but none that I found answer how to update all existing records but append new records.

And to answer the question, we have an existing workflow that takes data formatted like the output format and processes it. I need this data to flow through that same workflow.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to have one file for each unique date?

Comment: Yes. But each file should contain all most recent records up to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = df.sort_values('DataDate')

for d in df['DataDate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique():
    df.loc[df['DataDate'] <= d] \
      .groupby('PROG.ID', as_index=False).last() \
      .to_csv(r'd:/temp/File_{}.csv'.format(d), index=False)
```

Results:

**File_2007-01-01.csv**

```
PROG.ID,TITLE,STATUS,DataDate
KEY1,Key 1,A,2007-01-01
KEY2,Key 2,A,2007-01-01
```

**File_2008-07-01.csv**

```
PROG.ID,TITLE,STATUS,DataDate
KEY1,Key 1,A,2007-01-01
KEY2,Key 2,A,2007-01-01
KEY3,Key 3,A,2008-07-01
```

**File_2009-07-01.csv**

```
PROG.ID,TITLE,STATUS,DataDate
KEY1,Key 1,A,2007-01-01
KEY2,Key 2,I,2009-07-01
KEY3,Key 3,A,2008-07-01
```

**File_2010-01-01.csv**

```
PROG.ID,TITLE,STATUS,DataDate
KEY1,Key 1,A,2007-01-01
KEY2,Key 2,I,2009-07-01
KEY3,Key 3,A,2008-07-01
KEY4,Key 4,A,2010-01-01
```

Comment: Wouldn't this keep ALL `DataDate`s for a particular key (i.e., KEY2 has 2 records in the full file but should only appear one time in each file)?

Comment: To confirm, this does duplicate records instead of keeping the most recent.

Comment: Last night when I was pondering this I was thinking something like this would be what was necessary. Thank you for your help. This worked perfectly.

Comment: @dmonder, glad it helps :)